# How do I do an insert with a join

Tags: mysql

I want to take the result of this

```
SELECT * FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'foo'
```

And use it with this

```
INSERT INTO `projects-permissions` 
(`id`, `project`, `org`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, 'foo', ORG.ID)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `projects-permissions` (`id`, `project`, `org`) 
SELECT NULL, 'foo', ID 
FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'foo'
```

or a little shorter

```
INSERT INTO `projects-permissions` (`project`, `org`) 
SELECT slug, ID 
FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `projects-permissions` 
(`id`, `project`, `org`) 
SELECT null, slug, ID FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 1):

INSERT INTO `projects-permissions` 
(`id`, `project`, `org`) 
SELECT null, slug, org FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = "foo";