# How do I do an insert with multiple joins?

Tags: mysql

> Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094872/how-do-i-do-an-insert-with-a-join#37094886) question, but more advanced ...

I want to take the result of this

```
SELECT * FROM `orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'fooA'
```

And the result of this

```
SELECT * FROM `projects`
WHERE `slug` = 'fooB'
```

And use it with this

```
INSERT INTO `things` 
(`id`, `project`, `org`, `thingA`, `thingB`) 
VALUES 
(NULL, project.id, org.id, 'fooC', 'fooD')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `things` 
(`id`, `project`, `org`, `thingA`, `thingB`) 
SELECT NULL, `project`.`id`, `org`.`id`, 'fooC', 'fooD' FROM `projects`,`orgs`
WHERE `slug` = 'fooA' OR `slug` = 'fooB';
```

Comment: What happens if both values are the same? ie. `fooA` is the value of both slugs, but they represent different `id`s in either table. How does it know which I’m referring to?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck You get for example `project.id=2` from `slug='fooA'` in `projects` table and `org.id=3` from `slug='fooA'` in `orgs` table.

Comment: Oh, I see the distinction now, thank you for highlighting that